# GraphDB - Federated Query

Tags: sparql, graphdb, federated-queries

I would like to know how to perform a federated search on GraphDB. For example, to insert the code below in GraphDB, how should I do it? The idea is to add the content below to my local GraphDB.

```
#Locations of air accidents in wikidata - https://query.wikidata.org/
SELECT ?label ?coord ?place
WHERE
{
   ?subj wdt:P31 wd:Q744913  .
   ?subj wdt:P625 ?coord .
   ?subj rdfs:label ?label
   filter (lang(?label) = "en")
}
```

Comment: Use SPARQL 1.1 `SERVICE` feature. And you'll need an `INSERT WHERE` query if you want to add that data to your local repo. Also, there might a limit of the returned resultset size depending on the SPARQL endpoint - the reason for this is quite obvious, it's a shared service and too many/too expensive queries could block the whole service

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Could you send an example?

Comment: I mean, its should be more or less as I said: `INSERT {
  ?subj wdt:P31 wd:Q744913 .
  ?subj wdt:P625 ?coord .
  ?subj rdfs:label ?label .
}
WHERE
  { SERVICE <https://query.wikidata.org/sparql>
      { ?subj  wdt:P31     wd:Q744913 ;
               wdt:P625    ?coord ;
               rdfs:label  ?label
        FILTER ( lang(?label) = "en" )
      }
  }`

Comment: Hi Stanislav!

Thank you very much for sharing the knowledge.
From the Brazilian friend.

John.

Answer (score 1):

> Posting @UninformedUser's comment as an answer for better readability.

SPARQL 1.1 offers the `SERVICE` feature, described [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-federated-query/). You can use it to perform federated queries against Wikidata directly inside of GraphDB.

```
SELECT * WHERE {
    SERVICE <https://query.wikidata.org/sparql> {
        ?subj wdt:P31 wd:Q744913 ;
            wdt:P625 ?coord ;
            rdfs:label ?label
        FILTER (lang(?label) = "en")
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Richard!

Thank you very much for sharing the knowledge.
From the Brazilian friend.

John.

Answer (score 1):

To insert the data to your local GraphDB, use something like this:

```
INSERT {
        ?subj wdt:P31 wd:Q744913 ;
            wdt:P625 ?coord ;
            rdfs:label ?label
} WHERE {
    SERVICE <https://query.wikidata.org/sparql> {
        ?subj wdt:P31 wd:Q744913 ;
            wdt:P625 ?coord ;
            rdfs:label ?label
        FILTER (lang(?label) = "en")
    }
}
```

However, you'd probably want to unpack the coordinates and use some ontology that's easier to understand, eg:

```
PREFIX wgs: <http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#> # see http://prefix.cc/wgs.sparql
INSERT {
        ?subj a :AirAccident;
            wgs:lat ?lat; wgs:long ?long; 
            rdfs:label ?label
} WHERE {
    SERVICE <https://query.wikidata.org/sparql> {
      ?subj wdt:P31 wd:Q744913 ;
            p:P625/psv:P625  [wikibase:geoLatitude ?lat; wikibase:geoLongitude ?long];
            rdfs:label ?label
        FILTER (lang(?label) = "en")
    }
}
```

For the `p:P625, psv:P625, wikibase:geoLatitude` stuff, see https://github.com/nichtich/wdq#wikidata-ontology (and if you install it, `wdq help ontology` gives this color-coded)

Comment: Hi!
Thanks for the answers. However, I didn't understand the benefit of the second query.

Comment: `wdt:P625 ?coord` returns a string. `p:P625/psv:P625` unpacks that into lat & long, i.e. extracts structured data. It also translates to more understandable (`rdf:type a :AirAccident`) and more widely used (`wgs:lat; wgs:long`) ontology terms.